# Are references to Java enum values global?

Tags: java, enums, synchronization, locking

Let's say I have an enum with multiple values, for example:

```
public enum Category {
  A, B, C, D;
}
```

And would like to create a locking mechanism so that we are only processing one item per category at a single time.  My first idea was to do something like this:

```
Set categories = new HashSet();
for (Category cat : Category.values() {
  categories.put(cat);
}
```

and then when I need to acquire a lock, I do the following:

```
synchronized(categories.get(category)) {
  ....
}
```

will this work or are all references to an enum value global so if some other thread, elsewhere, did the same thing they would block each other?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you're using the right vocabulary to pose your question. It doesn't really make sense to ask "are all references global?" Also, there is no `Set#get()` method, nor do you need a set at all if you've already got a reference to the `category`.

Comment: Your question is flawed I think, your code does not compile. Can you please clarify/clean your question?

Answer (score 4):

Each enum value is a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Only one instance exists for the [classloader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader) which loaded the enum class. So yes, if two threads use an enum value as a lock, they will use the same lock and thus block each other.

Side note: your question would be clearer if you used valid, compiling Java code.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one `Category.A` instance, so all `synchronized(Category.A)` will block each other, which is what you are doing with your set.

You could use a private final [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) associated to your enum, fill it with `new Object()`s, make sure you don't modify the map, and use the object associated with the category as a lock for that category. That way you are sure that the lock is only used in that piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your enum will be visible in your project (package).
If you need to use this logick elsewhere, you will need to add reference to this project.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking.